# ElectronJS electron-builder build error in Raspberry Pi OS Buster

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, electron, raspberry-pi3, electron-builder

I followed a blog titled [Creating an Electron Application for the Raspberry Pi](https://azukidigital.com/blog/2019/electron-application-on-raspberry-pi/), regarding starting an Electron app in Raspberry Pi using the Buster OS and got it to compile.

But when it came to building the application, using the electron-builder, I keep getting the error of cannot execute... after running the command `electron-builder --dir --armv7l --linux deb` and can't figure what the issue is. I've attached the error [image]

Comment: I would refrain from adding the error message in an image as it makes it hard to search for the community. Also please provide steps to reproduce if applicable. What have you done already to try and solve the issue and why didn't that work?

Comment: The steps are fairly long, so I included the process I took to recreate the application from a blog post. Let me know what I can do to facilitate this question, or to input the steps if need be. Thanks in advance!